# Preventing repeated subsections in ToC using Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, slideshow

Using beamer class, I am adding slide transitions in a subsection `ABC` using `\pause` command 3 times. When I generate the Table of content using `\tableofcontents`, I get `ABC` mentioned 3 times in my table of content.

How to prevent the subsection title from appearing multiple times in Table of Contents?

Comment: Don't use `\subsection` inside of a frame. If this does not help, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter. Moving `subsection` outside the frame works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structural elements (like `\subsection`) should always be used outside the frame environment.